# Is it possible to send realtime commands from PC to PLC

Tags: simulation, plc

We are using a frequency inverter to power a servo motor. This has to be programmed using PLC. Is it possible to gather data from a running program, using values from that to control the movements / frequency of the inverter?

(as an example; We built a racing game, we'd like to build a simulation chair that can support a grown person and act on accelaration / braking etc in the game)

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible: Yes. How: depends on lots and lots of things. (Start with defining – precisely – "realtime".) PLCs are commonly controlled from other systems: there are standards for this (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPC_Foundation).

Comment: Thanks. I have been doing a lot of googling and found a software application that has helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe what your asking is possible. I personally use a VB script running on a PC to write to registers in a PLC... so that's one way to do it.